# Convert decimal number to minutes and seconds using VBA

Tags: vba, time, decimal, seconds

I have time represented by a decimal number that I need to convert to minutes and seconds in Excel using VBA.

Example: 
The number before the decimal point gives the minutes as 0.197683577  (0 minutes)
and the number multiplied by 60 gives the seconds = 0.197683577*60 = 11.86101462 (12 seconds)
= 0:12

I know I could do this by copying and pasting into text format and separating the number to the left and right using text to columns of the decimal point and then add ":" in between but there must be a way to calculate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VBA function didn't work for me but I found a workaround within Excel:

```
=TRUNC(W11/60)&":"&IF(ROUND(((W11/60-TRUNC(W11/60))*60),0)=0,"00",ROUND(((W11/60-TRUNC(W11/60))*60),0))`
```

Where `W11` is time in the form of a decimal number like `900.3201306`.
The result is in minutes `15:00`

Basically, you take the truncated decimal minutes minus the decimal minutes+seconds to give you seconds only.  Then you take the `decimal seconds * 60` to give you `seconds+milliseconds`.  Round this to give you seconds.  If seconds are 0 then write "00" to get the correct format. Then add the truncated minutes plus the seconds.

This formula seems to be working.

Answer (score 4):

```
Public Function FromDecimalTime(ByVal t As Double) As Date
  FromDecimalTime = TimeSerial(0, Fix(t), (t - Fix(t)) * 60)
End Function
```

Same with a formula:

```
=TIME(0,TRUNC(A1),(A1-TRUNC(A1))*60)
```

Well, not the same actually. `TimeSerial` will round number of seconds according to rounding rules (`11.86` -> `12`), and `TIME` will truncate (`11.86` -> `11`). But you can apply a rounding function to its last argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Since I wanted an integer for the minutes I used Fix(decim) & Format(val, ":ss") to get the proper format.  I'm not sure if there is a time format code to generate this but it seems to work.


'Sub aaaaaaaMacro1()
   
Dim decim As Double
decim = Range("AB11").Value

Dim val As Date
val = TimeSerial(0, Fix(decim), (decim - Fix(decim)) * 60)

MsgBox Fix(decim) & Format(val, ":ss")
    
End Sub'